# Linq to Entity Join table with multiple OR conditions

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I need to write a Linq-Entity state that can get the below SQL query

```
SELECT  RR.OrderId
FROM    dbo.TableOne RR
        JOIN dbo.TableTwo  M ON RR.OrderedProductId = M.ProductID OR RR.SoldProductId= M.ProductID
WHERE   RR.StatusID IN ( 1, 4, 5, 6, 7 )
```

I am stuck with the below syntax

```
 int[] statusIds = new int[] { 1, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
            using (Entities context = new Entities())
            {
                var query = (from RR in context.TableOne
                             join M in context.TableTwo on new { RR.OrderedProductId, RR.SoldProductId} equals new { M.ProductID }
                             where RR.CustomerID == CustomerID 
                             && statusIds.Any(x => x.Equals(RR.StatusID.Value))
                             select RR.OrderId).ToArray();
            }
```

this gives me below error

**Error 50  The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.**

How can I do a Multiple condition join for a table.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You don't have to use the join syntax. Adding the predicates in a `where` clause has the same effect and you can add more conditions:

```
var query = (from RR in context.TableOne
             from M in context.TableTwo 
             where RR.OrderedProductId == M.ProductID
                   || RR.SoldProductId == M.ProductID // Your join
             where RR.CustomerID == CustomerID 
                   && statusIds.Any(x => x.Equals(RR.StatusID.Value))
             select RR.OrderId).ToArray();
```

Comment: Well this worked. I was looking on SO and found something like where where RR.OrderedProductId / RR.SoldProductId equals M.ProductID  but that did not work for my code.

Answer (score 7):

Change your query syntax from using `join` to using an additional `from` clause

```
  var query = (from RR in context.TableOne
               from M in context.TableTwo.Where(x => x.ProductID == RR.OrderedProductId || x.ProductID == RR.SoldProductId)
               where statusIds.Any(x => x.Equals(RR.StatusID.Value))
               select RR.OrderId).ToArray();
```

Comment: Your both answers worked for me. Sorry, I can select only one answer. So I am giving you up vote and selecting @gert Arnold as answer

Answer (score 3):

Multiple Joins :

```
var query = (from RR in context.TableOne
             join M in context.TableTwo on new { oId = RR.OrderedProductId,  sId = RR.SoldProductId} equals new { oId = M.ProductID, sId = M.ProductID }
             where RR.CustomerID == CustomerID 
             && statusIds.Any(x => x.Equals(RR.StatusID.Value))
             select RR.OrderId).ToArray();
```

Comment: Will create an `on ... and ...` not a `on ... or ...` query