# LINQ: How to write multiple conditions for "on" caluse?

Tags: c#, linq

I have difficulty in translating SQL to LINQ statement.

Here is SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM dataTableA INNER JOIN dataTableB ON dataTableA.ID =dataTableB.SNo OR 
         dataTableA.Address = dataTableB.Address 
         WHERE (dataTableA.Name = dataTableB.UserName)
```

It is `OR` part in `On` clause where I don't know how to write LINQ syntax. I have tried with below quote without `OR` condition. Kindly advise.

```
var matches = from rowA  in dataTableA.AsEnumerable()
                join rowB in dataTableB.AsEnumerable()
                on  rowA["ID"].ToString().Trim() equals rowB["SNo"].ToString().Trim()  
                where  rowA["Name"].ToString().Trim() == rowB["UserName"].ToString().Trim() 
                select new { rowA, rowB } ;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq to Entity Join table with multiple OR conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887223/linq-to-entity-join-table-with-multiple-or-conditions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
var matches = from rowA  in dataTableA.AsEnumerable()
              from  rowB in dataTableB.AsEnumerable().Where(x=>x.SNo==rowA.ID || x.Address ==rowA.Address) .AsEnumerable()              
               where  rowA["Name"].ToString().Trim() == rowB["UserName"].ToString().Trim() 
                    select new { rowA, rowB } ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this showing error message "
System.Data.DataTable does not contain definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTable' coould be found" at dataTableB.Where(x=>...) part.

Comment: I have made a little changes and it worked well. Greatly appreciated your help.

Comment: @HtetThuzar Not say thanks if it is help out then given vot and right mark

Comment: we can also use a more straight forward `join`

Answer (score 1):

You can use composite keys to join on both `ID` **and** `Adress`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907099.aspx

```
dataTableA.AsEnumerable().join(dataTableB.AsEnumerable(),
  ta => new {ta.ID, ta.Adress}, tb => new {tb.SNo, tb.Adress}, 
  (ta, tb) => new {ta, tb})
```

If you want to join on `ID` **or** `Adress`, you can union 2 joins, which *I think* should still be faster than n `where`s: [Why is LINQ JOIN so much faster than linking with WHERE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551264/why-is-linq-join-so-much-faster-than-linking-with-where)

```
dataTableA.AsEnumerable().join(dataTableB.AsEnumerable(),
  ta => ta.ID, tb => tb.SNo, (ta, tb) => new {ta, tb})
.union(dataTableA.AsEnumerable().join(dataTableB.AsEnumerable(),
  ta => ta.Adress, tb => tb.Adress, (ta, tb) => new {ta, tb}))
```

Comment: Thanks. But my requirement is to join two tables on either ID or Address if Name in both tables are same. The composite keys idea will join two tables only on condition that all Name, ID and Address are same.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var matches = dataTableA.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(a => new {
                    RowA = a,
                    RowB = dataTableB.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(b => ((b["SNo"] == a["ID"]) || (b["Address"].Equals(a["Address"]))))
                })
        .Where(pair => pair.RowB != null) //to replicate the inner-join
        .Where(pair => pair.RowA["Name"].Equals(pair.RowB["Username"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

After minor changes to Mukesh Kalgude's answer, problem solved. Below here is finalized working codes. Thanks to all for your kind suggestions.

```
var matches = from rowA  in dataTableA.AsEnumerable()
              from  rowB in    dataTableB.AsEnumerable().Where(x=>x["SNo"]==rowA["ID"] || x["Address"]==rowA["Address"]) .AsEnumerable()              
             where  rowA["Name"].ToString().Trim() == rowB["UserName"].ToString().Trim() 
             select new { rowA, rowB } ;
```