# Linq to sql join with multiple "OR" filters

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I need to implement this in Linq-to-sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM dbo.Collector_Capital_Equipment c
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Lab_Space s ON c.Room = s.Entry_Bar_Code 
                                OR c.HomeRoom = s.Entry_Bar_Code
WHERE s.id = 1021645
```

All the research I've done on this says that linq-to-sql can't support an "OR" multiple join, and the suggestions are to instead do two joins like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM dbo.Collector_Capital_Equipment c
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Lab_Space s ON c.Room = s.Entry_Bar_Code 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Lab_Space s2 ON c.HomeRoom = s2.Entry_Bar_Code
WHERE s.id = 1021645
```

Those aren't actually the same query though as they'll return different results.  Short of just putting the raw SQL into my C# program at this point, is there any way to accomplish the above?

Comment: Is there something like `s.Entry_Bar_Code IN (c.Room, HomeRoom)`?

Comment: See my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) - basically, use `Where` on a cross join.

Comment: Near duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15887223/861716

Comment: @GertArnold CROSS JOIN with multiple conditions in where clause is not the same as LEFT JOIN with multiple conditions.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda You're right, it's not the same thing, It's the same idea though: abandon join syntax and use a predicate.

Comment: @GertArnold It all depends what OP really wants to achieve. In his scenario it is simple `INNER JOIN` - probably he is not aware of that. With correct `LEFT JOIN` you get different resultset. **[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e205e31374999eb1d92ff59819fc5cc7)**

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Yeah, that's tricky. If it's inner join, I'd prefer an EXIST statement for that matter, wouldn't require DISTINCT.

Comment: There may not be a room or homeroom set which was why I used the left

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from beginning. If you use `WHERE` with column from `OUTER JOIN` table it means that your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM dbo.Collector_Capital_Equipment c
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Lab_Space s ON c.Room = s.Entry_Bar_Code 
                                OR c.HomeRoom = s.Entry_Bar_Code
WHERE s.id = 1021645
```

is logically equivalent to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM dbo.Collector_Capital_Equipment c
JOIN dbo.Lab_Space s 
  ON c.Room = s.Entry_Bar_Code 
  OR c.HomeRoom = s.Entry_Bar_Code
WHERE s.id = 1021645;
```

And this could be achieved with `CROSS JOIN`(pseudocode):

```
var q = from c in Collector_Capital_Equipment
       from s in Lab_Space
       where s.id == 1021645 
          && (s.Entry_Bar_Code == c.Room || c.HomeRoom == s.Entry_Bar_Code)
       select ...
```

---

I assume that you really want to generate query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM dbo.Collector_Capital_Equipment c
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Lab_Space s 
  ON (c.Room = s.Entry_Bar_Code OR c.HomeRoom = s.Entry_Bar_Code)
  AND s.id = 1021645
```

which could be represented as:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM dbo.Collector_Capital_Equipment c
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Lab_Space s 
  ON c.Room = s.Entry_Bar_Code AND s.id = 1021645
INTERSECT
SELECT c.*
FROM dbo.Collector_Capital_Equipment c
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Lab_Space s 
  ON c.HomeRoom = s.Entry_Bar_Code AND s.id = 1021645
```

And above query could be achieved with LINQ using set operators.

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2f6ace10de7767612dcafd2aa046506d)**

Comment: You're raising good points here, esp. the condition on `s.Id` turning this into a de-facto inner join.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I've ever seen someone use an OR clause on a join before. Does MS SQL Server even support that in SQL?

I'd probably just split this off into two queries, to be honest.

```
SELECT entry_bar_code 
FROM dbo.Lab_Space WHERE id = 1021645;
```

With the result from that being fed into

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM dbo.Collector_Capital_Equipment 
WHERE c.room == <barcode> OR c.homeRoom == <barcode>
```

Comment: An `OR` clause in a join predicate is in fact entirely legitimate. You can structure your join predicates with as much complexity as where clauses.

Comment: `Does MS SQL Server even support that in SQL?` Of course it works in SQL Server, even more any condition that could be used with `ON` clause. **[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f7016d62c98810bc14f7a7136f51a722)**