# Inner join with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I am trying to join the following tables in EF Core (SQL Server)

`Table: Data`

| Id | Name | ParentId | ChildId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dina | 100 | 101 |
| 2 | Lucy | 100 | `NULL` |
| 3 | Sam | 100 | 102 |
| 4 | Ben | 200 | 201 |
| 5 | Max | 200 | 202 |
| 6 | Lily | 300 | `NULL` |

`Table: Security`

| Id | UserId | ParentId | ChildId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xyz | 100 | `NULL` |
| 2 | xyz | 200 | `NULL` |
| 3 | abc | 100 | 101 |
| 4 | abc | 200 | 202 |

Foreign keys are set up. In addition to the mentioned tables, there is a "Parents" and a "Childs" table.

**Business logic**

A user can either have access on parent level (ChildId = null) or on Child level (ChildId not null). Example

- User `xyz` has access to all `Data` records except to `Lily` (`Data.Id = 6`).
- User `abc` has only access to `Data` records with `ChildIds` 101 and 202, i.e.:

  - Dina (Id = 1)
  - Max (Id = 5)

T-SQL query

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Data AS d
    INNER JOIN Security AS s ON
        (
            ( s.ParentId = d.ParentId AND s.ChildId IS NULL ) 
            OR
            ( s.ChildId = d.ChildId AND s.ChildId IS NOT NULL )
        )
        AND
        s.UserId = 'xyz'
```

What's the best way to translate this into an EFCore lambda expression?
The examples I found so far are all doing a simple join with one column only.

Comment: Do you have FK relationships defined in your database? And do you have navigation-proper and `Include` working in EF?

Comment: I'm curious how the design of this `Security` table came into being - it's not relevant so the question, for the sake of my curiosity, what does `ParentId` and `ChildId` _mean_ in your domain-model?

Comment: @Dai, 
I have navigational properties, but I have to admit that I didnt check if it's handling the joins correctly with the current setup. In general, my includes work fine. But they have been simple joins on a single id field.

ParentId and ChildId are organizational structures. For example, parent = corp hq, child is a branch/ division. Data can either be on corp level (parentid != null, childid = null) or on division level (parentid !=null & childid != null)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think using EF *itself* is an appropriate choice here, because EF still only works well with relationships between tables based on key-tuples (i.e.: foreign keys and primary keys), but your `ParentId` and `ChildId` columns are not keys, and Linq (even when used outside of EF) does not make it easy to perform any kind of `JOIN` besides tuple-equality.

I think a better overall solution would be to define a `FUNCTION`  in your database that implements the `Data`-`Security` match logic, and then you can use *that* UDF from within EF (don't use a `PROCEDURE`: table-valued `FUNCTIONS` are much simpler and most important: they can be composed inside other queries, [even in Linq+EF queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping#mapping-a-queryable-function-to-a-table-valued-function), which you can't do with `PROCEDURES`).

I don't know if you need a function that does a single access check (in which case use a scalar `FUNCTION`) or if you want a table-valued function that returns the set of permitted `UserId` values for a given `Data.Id` - or the set of permitted `Data.Id` values for a given `UserId`.

---

Nevertheless, without using a `FUNCTION`, and keeping things entirely in EF, means *compromising* your query to fit within the limitations of Linq's expressiveness - and EF's ability to generate SQL from that Linq expression (remember that EF and Linq *are not the same thing*).

So I think the best way is to make a `UNION` of two inner-queries (aka derived-tables): the first half is the `Security.ChildId IS NULL` results, the second half is the `Security.ChildId IS NOT NULL` results.

In SQL this would be:

```
SELECT
    d.*
FROM
    dbo.Data AS d
    INNER JOIN Security s ON
        s.ParentId = d.ParentId
WHERE
    s.ChildId IS NULL
    AND
    s.UserId = @userId
    
UNION ALL

SELECT
    d.*
FROM
    dbo.Data AS d
    INNER JOIN Security s ON
        s.ParentId = d.ParentId
        AND
        s.ChildId = d.ChildId
WHERE
    s.ChildId IS NOT NULL
    AND
    s.UserId = @userId
```

Note how in the above query the `INNER JOIN ON` expression is now an *exact tuple equality* and the other criteria (like `s.ChildId IS NOT NULL` and `s.UserId = @userId`) is moved to the `WHERE` part. This shouldn't make a difference to the query's execution plan, but I think it makes the query conceptually easier to understand.

And so because the `JOIN` criteria are now expressed *only* as tuple-equalities, it can now be converted to a Linq query.

```
public static async Task< List<Data> > GetDataThatUserCanAccessAsync( MyDbContext db, String userId, CancellationToken ct = default )
{
    IQueryable<Data> firstHalf = db.Data
        .Join(
            inner: db.Security,
            innerKeySelector: s => new { s.ParentId },
            outerKeySelector: d => new { d.ParentId },
            resultSelector: ( d, s ) => new { d, s }
        )
        .Where( t => t.s.ChildId == null )
        .Where( t => t.s.UserId == userId )
        .Select( t => t.d );

    IQueryable<Data> secondHalf = db.Data
        .Join(
            inner: db.Security,
            innerKeySelector: s => new { s.ParentId, s.ChildId },
            outerKeySelector: d => new { d.ParentId, d.ChildId },
            resultSelector: ( d, s ) => new { d, s }
        )
        .Where( t => t.s.ChildId != null )
        .Where( t => t.s.UserId == userId )
        .Select( t => t.d );

    IQueryable<Data> query = firstHalf.Concat( secondHalf );

    List<Data> results = await query.ToListAsync( ct ).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return results;
}
```

When Linq is translated to SQL, there are some subtleties to be aware-of:

- SQL's `UNION` = Linq's `.Concat`.
- SQL's `UNION ALL` = Linq's `.Union`.

---

I prefer to explicit parameter labels whenever I use `.Join` in Linq because I keep on forgetting the exact order of the parameters, but it can be shorted down to just this:

(I strongly recommend you look at the generated SQL in both cases: it *should* be identical for both, but might also be different... and because this is a JOIN on non-key columns it's important that you ensure your database's `INDEX` objects for the `ParentId` and `ChildId` are correct and the `STATISTICS` objects are maintained (you *are* rebuilding them every week, *right*?), otherwise these queries (even in pure SQL without EF) will likely run very slowly if either table has more than a few hundred rows.

```
public static async Task< List<Data> > GetDataThatUserCanAccessAsync( MyDbContext db, String userId, CancellationToken ct = default )
{
    List<Data> results = await db.Data
        .Join( db.Security, s => new { s.ParentId }, d => new { d.ParentId }, ( d, s ) => new { d, s } )
        .Where( t => t.s.ChildId == null && t.s.UserId == userId )
        .Select( t => t.d )
        .Concat(
            db.Data
            .Join( db.Security, s => new { s.ParentId, s.ChildId }, d => new { d.ParentId, d.ChildId }, ( d, s ) => new { d, s } )
            .Where( t => t.s.ChildId != null && t.s.UserId == userId )
            .Select( t => t.d )
        )
        .ToListAsync( ct )
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    return results;
```

I'm really not a fan of how Linq's `.Concat` and `.Union` methods are extensions on `IQueryable<T>` whereas in SQL they're top-level operators - which results in aesthetically unpleasing asymmetrical queries.

Comment: Thanks so much for the extended explanation! So far, i have been able to implement all my security requirements in Linq in a reusable structure. However, I have the feeling a function is the way to go here. I will explore that further and check how I can built this into my design. Just one additional thing, I found this explanation: https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/15887223/linq-to-entity-join-table-with-multiple-or-conditions Not sure yet if this would work with my problem. I struggle to convert this into a lambda expression (which I need because of the rest of my code)

Comment: @atlan Please don't link to the third-party and _very unofficial_ entityframework.net site, it's just ripping-off StackOverflow: here's the original link you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887223/linq-to-entity-join-table-with-multiple-or-conditions - anyway, w.r.t. _that_ query: it works _in that specific case_ because their predicate was **not** really a `JOIN` criteria, so it works by moving it to the `WHERE` clause (which is what I've also done in my answer if you look closely), but the `JOIN` criteria should always be based on _tuple-equality_ and nothing else.

Comment: Noted, thanks. I tried to get the actual stackoverflow.com link, but couldn't find it.

Comment: @atlan Yeah, they're sneaky about that, but if you scroll to the _very bottom_ of the page there's a "Read more on StackOverflow" link in an orange rectangle.

Comment: @atlan the answer linked there is a filtered cartesian-product. The results will be the same, and the database will probably do something smart with its query optimizer to wind up with the same thing but it's not guaranteed. Performance may be very different.

Answer (score 1):

I was writing something like @Dai's LINQ answer, but I used query syntax instead (which I prefer over fluent syntax for joins). Adapting the query portion of @Dai's solution, it would look like this (note my comments):

```cs
    var firstHalf = 
       from d in db.Data
       join s in db.Security
       on s.ParentId equals d.ParentId
       where s.ChildId == null && s.UserId == userId
       select d; // or new { d, s } <-- if you want to capture both data and security parts

    var secondHalf = 
        from d in db.Data
        join s in db.Security
        on new { d.ParentId, d.ChildId }
        equals new { s.Parentid, s.ChildId }
        where s.ChildId != null // <-- this where may not be necessary if d.ChildId  must be nonnull
        select d; // or new { d, s } if you want both Data and Security parts

    var query = firstHalf.Concat(secondHalf);
```

Lastly, I will strongly suggest checking the generated SQL and its execution plan. I've been surprised by both. If you do not check, you may be surprised by the complexity of the generated SQL and performance differences.

Comment: The reason I always use the extension-method syntax (instead of the `from`/`join` keyword syntax) is because _inevitably_ a query will need to use a feature that the keyword syntax doesn't support (e.g. `Skip/Take`) or dynamically adding more `.Where` clauses at runtime, not to mention the final `.ToListAsync` call - which means having to _tediously rewrite the entire thing_ in extension-method syntax. (Not criticizing, just sharing my experience :) )

Comment: @Dai - I usually pick one syntax or the other (fluent or query-comprehension). I didn't intend my opinion to be a dig on your solution (which I gave you a +1 for), I just wanted to provide atlan an alternative.

Comment: _You're fine_ - I know you weren't criticizing or anything close to the sort

Comment: The company I work for has a large legacy system with lots of huge stored procedures. A couple years back they settled on EF/EFCore and along with it set a policy of no new SPROCs. ...and a lot of that is being replaced with AWS/Dynamo-DB and serverless -- so much for my EF/Linq expertise. :)

Comment: "a policy of no new SPROCs" - I hope that's not a blanket policy without any room for compromise. I totally _get_ that sprocs have been inappropriately used in so many places, but they're still essential for some things. I trust you can still create `FUNCTION` and `VIEW` objects, though? If not... then I'd seriously consider jumping-ship because that's such a braindead policy otherwise.